# Flink web upload jar pending not

Tags: apache-flink

upload jar ,pending
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
When I upload a file that is not at the end of '.jar', I immediately report an error and print an error, but the normal jar file does not respond, there is no error log, and my jar file is too small to be too large. Did not query the error log, could you tell me how to check?

Normal upload，Upload quickly and save to the server.